# React-popup popup not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, popup

I am using React-popup to create a contact form as a popup. I am trying to integrate my popup in the following way:

In the App.js I have:

```
import Popup from 'react-popup'
```

I have an onclick listener on a Button element as follows:

```
<Button onClick={listen} className="button" size="large">
    <Text fontSize={4} > Get Started</Text>
</Button>
```

And the listen function trying to implement the popup as follows:

```
function listen() {
console.log('listen');
let mySpecialPopup = Popup.register({
    title: 'I am test',
    content: 'test',
    buttons: {
        left: ['cancel'],
        right: ['ok']
    }
});
Popup.register(mySpecialPopup);
}
```

I am able to see 'listen' in console but nothing happens with the popup, no alert no errors either. Is this is correct way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

**First Issue:**

Did you render the `<Popup />` component anywhere as described in the section "Setup" in the [documentation](http://minutemailer.github.io/react-popup/)?

**Second Issue:**

Did you mean to call `Popup.queue(mySpecialPopup);` instead of `Popup.register(mySpecialPopup);`?